# Can we use the power of ice to float to make free electricity?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion, ice, renewable-energy

ice and water have a volume to weight ratio of 12/11 
so 11 tons of ice will support 1 ton of weight 
1 ton of ice takes 1000 watts or 12000 b.t.u. of energy to be produced

question is, at what depth would i have to make my ice for it to float to the surface in a continuous conveyor belt and bucket type system where the floating energy powers the lot?

Comment: I think you will find that the necessary energy to produce ice is not a constant but depends on the ambient pressure.

Comment: all searches show pressure has very little effect on the freezing point , very deep water is usually cold though this will help.

Comment: You appear to be asking about creating free energy, which is in conflict with the Law of Conservation of Energy.

Comment: 1000 watts does not equal 12000 btu. The watt is a unit of power, not energy.

Answer (score 3):

There are two factors you're ignoring that keep this from working:

First, ice expands as it freezes.  If you freeze a kilogram of water at the bottom of the ocean, you need to displace an additional ~100g of water, which takes exactly as much energy as you'd gain from letting that kilogram of ice lift a 100g weight to the surface.  This is the usual problem with buoyancy-based perpetual motion machines: it takes exactly as much energy to establish the buoyant condition as you gain from exploiting the buoyancy.

Second, the freezing point of water increases with pressure.  At the surface of the ocean, ice melts at 0˚C.  But if you take your freshly-melted 0˚C water back down to the bottom of the ocean, you'll find that the freezing point is now -9.5˚C: not only do you need to extract heat to freeze the water, you need to cool it down first.

Answer (score 1):

So 1 kg of ice raising from the bottom of the deepest ocean trench can lift a 100g object to the surface. This is about 11,000 m displacement for a 1N weight. The work done is 11 kJ. To freeze 1 kg of water you need to extract about 320 KJ of thermal energy from the water at 0 Celsius. So if you have a refrigerator with a coefficient of performance (COP) of about 35 you may break even. 
Typical refrigerator COPs are in the range 2-5 I believe.

Comment: cheers nasu for replying , the further the ice floats up the more lifting capacity can be retrieved , 11 kj of energy to real up a 100g weight ,ok, the 11kj is going to increase with depth . if the fridge system is a heat pump can more energy be available.

Comment: sorry i see you made the sum of 11000 m there

Comment: A refrigerator is a heat pump, in terms of its thermodynamics. The difference is just in the way you use it (not to heat up the room but to cool the inside of the box). .